# Cordova Ionic application is preventing tablet from sleeping

Tags: android, ionic-framework, permissions, cordova-plugins

I am creating an Ionic app based on a template I purchased Quizionic.

All I have done is change questions in DB and added some pages to template folder. The code is a mix of Ionic and HTML. There have been no other changes to `config.xml`, other than name etc.  All plugins are the same as per instructions:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-extension
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-payment-iap
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
cordova plugin add https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy.git
```

Quizionic comes with APK and asks for 2 permissions  (as per pic)

I created the APK on iMac (Cordova Ionic) and install it on Samsung tablet and Samsung phone.

My app asks for 3 permissions(as per pic)

Something in my app is asking to **prevent tablet sleeping**  (as per pic)  I can't locate what would cause this.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image: Prevent tablet sleeping]

Comment: please check "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />" is not added in your app.. you need to check in AndroidManifest.xml or may be in your android and tablet setting it's keep on like see https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/system-tools-prevent-tabletphone-sleeping

Comment: these are the only permissions in manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>

Comment: The setting on tablet show as per pic above